# MongoDB find the max value in embed document

Tags: mongodb, find, max

Here is my collection, and I want to find the student who got the max grade in Biology course.

I try this:

```
db.course.find(
{"Course_Name": 'Biology', "First_Name": 1, "Last_Name" :1}
).sort( {"Grade": -1 } ).limit(1)
```

But nothing comes out... Can anyone tell me why and how to fix it? 
Thanks!!

-----Collections--------

```
 {
        Course_ID:13,
        Course_Name: 'Biology',
        Students:[
            {student_id:001,
            First_Name:'Dave',
            Last_Name: 'Davis',
            Grade: 78},

            {student_id: 003,
            First_Name:'Thomas',
            Last_Name: 'Thompson',
            Grade: 80}
        ]
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution goes here:

```
  db.course.aggregate([{
        $match: {
            "Course_Name": 'Biology'
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind: "$Students"
    },
    {
        $sort: {
            "Students.Grade": -1
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            "Students.First_Name": 1,
            "Students.Last_Name": 1
        }
    },
    {
        $limit: 1
    }
])
```